# Why is the following code an infinite loop?

Tags: c, for-loop

The given C code segment is as follows. What is the number of iterations for the 'for' loop?

```
#define DELTA sizeof(int) 
int i; 
for (i = 10; i - DELTA >= 0; i -= DELTA)
```

I expected the loop to run three times, but it turns into an infinite loop when executed in VSCode

Comment: `sizeof(int)` has `size_t` type. When used in an arithmetic expression, all other terms are converted to `size_t` ... and that means `i - DELTA` or `(size_t)((size_t)i - DELTA)` **is always positive (or zero)**

Comment: My compiler (`gcc ... -Wconversion ...`) complains about the change to the sign of the result.

Answer (score 3):

This happens due to the **usual arithmetic conversions** causing all operands in the comparison to have an unsigned type, resulting in a comparison that is always true.

The macro `DELTA` expands to `sizeof(int)`, and the result of the `sizeof` operand has type `size_t` which is an unsigned type.  So given its use in this expression:

```
i - DELTA >= 0
```

The subexpression `i - DELTA` involves operands of type `int` and `size_t`, so a common type must be determined for the expression.  This is defined in section 6.3.1.8p1 of the [C standard](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) covering the usual arithmetic conversions.  The relevant part is as follows:

> Otherwise, if the operand that has unsigned integer type has rank
> greater or equal to the rank of the type of the other operand, then
> the operand with signed integer type is converted to the type of the
> operand with unsigned integer type.

Given that a `size_t` is at least as large as an `int`, the above clause applies, so the value of `i` is converted to type `size_t` and the result has type `size_t`.  So now we have a comparison that checks whether the expression `i - DELTA` is non-negative.  Since the type of this expression is unsigned, the comparison will always be true, and the result is that you have an infinite loop.

If you want things to run as you expect, you'll need to cast the unsigned value to a signed type in the comparison:

```
for (i = 10; i - (int)DELTA >= 0; i -= DELTA)
```

Comment: Pedantic: "Given that a size_t is at least as large as an int" --> Yes, that is very common, yet not specified.  `INT_MAX >= SIZE_MAX` is possible.

Answer (score -3):

```
for (i = 0; i > DELTA && i>= DELTA = 0; i -= DELTA)
```

i must be more then delta or loop will never terminate

Comment: `DELTA = 0` is an "assignment", not a compare.  Want that?